# Python Kivy Critical Text Error. Unable to Find any valuable Text provider

Tags: python, kivy

Hello I recently started to program in Python and I wanted to start with Gui (Kivy) but I have a bunch of errors.

I installed Kivy through pip and I had no problems, but when I run a basic App all crashes. 
My Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

I get this error Message:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Sebi\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-02-21_41.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
  File "C:\Users\Sebi\PycharmProjects\CookieClicker\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Sebi\PycharmProjects\CookieClicker\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "C:\Users\Sebi\PycharmProjects\CookieClicker\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Sebi\PycharmProjects\CookieClicker\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

I know there are a other Problems on Stackoverflow like this, but there is no answer for my Problem.

Comment: Did you follow [these](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#installation-on-windows) installation instructions? Note that there are several requirements that must be installed along with `kivy` itself.

Comment: I just checked that I missed a command. if you woundn´t have wrote that command I probably would have stoped python. For others with the same problem. You must execute it via Command Line.

Answer (score 1):

sdl2 should already be included in your installations. Your problem mainly lies in this line:

```
pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

"PIL" is short for Python Imaging Library, which handles image file formats. If your program doesn't know what to do with images like PNG and JPEG, it can't have a GUI. It's also responsible for image manipulation like stretching/skewing, blurring, transparency levels, color changing, and likely most important in this example, adding text to images (aka your button). According to its [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library), PIL has been deprecated in favor of Pillow. Fortunately, Pillow is backwards compatible.

I have seen this error before in one of my own projects. Try this:

```
pip install Pillow
```

This is optional, but if you ever decide to use pygame as well, pygame can serve as your source for [Text]  AND [Window]. "img_pygame" will also be added as a provider for [Image]. I use it for my kivy android apps.

```
pip install pygame
```

You will have to import these.

Answer (score 0):

I do this on Ubuntu (WSL on Windows and it *should work on Ubuntu*):

```py
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev
```